# In determinstic finite automata is there any possibility that every state is final state?

Tags: finite-automata

Is there any limit that final states should not more than some number(2,3,...) ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we have the regex `a*` we could express it as a state machine with one state with a loop. It's both the initial and final state. So yes, all states are final here.

[image: Finite State machine with one state looped to itself]